# Optimal memory storage, nested lists vs. flat lists

Tags: python, memory

I have a fairly large amount of data that needs to be stored in memory in Python, and i'm trying to work out how to save memory space as i'm continually running out of RAM.

I have restricted myself to use only basic Python methods like lists, dicts and tuples as i have found, that these often have a huge advantage in speed when i need to read/write the data.

How much am i penalized memory-wise for organizing my data in nested lists/dicts/tuples vs. just one flat list/dict/tuple?

Nested example:

```
[
    [
        [ a ],
        [ b ],
        [ c ]
    ],
    [
        [ d ],
        [ e ],
        [ f ]
    ],
]
```

Flat list:

```
[ a, b, c, d, e, f ]
```

1st edit: Data is a mix of string, float and int values.

2nd edit: Context as requested: These are small datasets for use in a neural network. The data cannot readily be split up or handled in chunks, as it will impair the training process, or require a large amount of the code to be rewritten. I have 32gb of RAM available.

Comment: You are penalized significantly. Each list comes with significant overhead as it is yet another pointer to a structure which needs to store length & capacity. Assuming `abcdef` are mere numbers I'd estimate the flat list taking probably less than one third of the memory, as each list will take more memory than a number.

Comment: Inside the interpreter a list is represented as a struct with a bunch of values (integers, pointers etc.), so adding more lists obviously leads to more memory consumption.

Comment: each character in 'abcdef' is in my case a small sublist containing a short dataset of a string, some floats and an int. - Will i still be able to go down to approximately 1/3 by using a flat list? - Can i use a flat dict instead of a list, as it would help greatly in organizing my indexes?

Comment: @skywalkerdk without knowing your use case and how the data looks, it's impossible to tell. The only advice I can give is to use tuples wherever immutability does not restrict you, since tuples use less memory than lists.

Comment: How much data are we talking about here? How much RAM do you have? What OS? Generally, if the amount of data is that massive then you should be using a database. Even if you optimise as best you can (for RAM storage), what happens if/when the source data gets bigger? It might work one day but not the next

Comment: @AlexF i have just run some code, and it seems that using tuples instead of lists, can save roughly about 10% memory.

Comment: Given the comments here I think you should give more context: what are you doing with this data? Why does it all need to be in memory. As mentioned above as well, how much memory do you have? It's hard to think of a scenario where you'd need 8-16GB+ of mixed strings and floats all accessible at once, could you break it into chunks and process them separately by loading them from a file?

Comment: Voting to close this as it's far too vague

Answer (score 1):

If your data is all of the same type, especially if it is primitive types (int, float, character, **not** str though) try using numpy arrays. Numpy stores data as a flat list but let's you access it like it's nested, and will generally use less memory as it is implemented to be more memory and speed efficient than lists. Keep in mind though that this only applies to rectangular arrays (ie. each sublist must have the same length).

Comment: The data is a mix of string, float and integer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Kraigolas said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72578178/6900729), if your data is numeric and you can store it as a flat list, you could use arrays from the [array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) which are optimized for efficient data storage. It also comes as a part of the standard library, so you'll not end up with any additional dependencies, assuming you're not using numpy already.

Comment: The data is a mix of string, float and integer.